# How to pass url in Fileuploader as argument?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

**I have multiple backend api's to upload a photo and I want to pass url through parameters.**

Link for the plugin: [github](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API)

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({

      url: PASS_FILE_NAME, // here i want to pass apis through paramters

      queueLimit: 1,

      removeAfterUpload: true,
  });

  // FILTERS

  uploader.filters.push({

      name: 'imageFilter',

      fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {

          var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';

      return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;

      }

  });
```